# Application 105 Dialog page 11 cannot be rendered successfully

Tags: oracle-apex-19.1

Oracle Apex application:

I'm trying to redirect to another page by javascript, but the following error appears:

```
"Application 105 Dialog page 11 cannot be rendered successfully. 
Ensure the page template in use on page 11 is of template type "Dialog page",
with appropriate JavaScript dialog initialization, dialog closure and dialog
cancel code defined."
```

Here is my code:

```
function openPopup (P10_IN) {
    var url;
    url = 'f?p=105:11:5992241694125::::P11_IN:'+P10_IN ;
    w = open(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have set the page you want to redirect to as `Appearance - Page Mode: "Modal Dialog"`.

Set it to `Appearance - Page Mode: "Normal"` and it should work as you expect.

Comment: thanks ,  but i need the page  open on modal dialog  type .

Comment: That is more complicated then than what you are trying. See this answer here for help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52122692/7435198