# how to display region in apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYASC.png)

`I have created a new region for static where when this navbar is clicked the region appears and the rest is hidden please help me how to make the code work

My hope is that when the button is clicked, the region appears

because I have 3 regions and also 3 Static IDs in each region Type:Interactive Report`

Comment: Please refer the below link, it may helpful to you.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022407/open-modal-dialog-through-javascript-oracle-apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022407/open-modal-dialog-through-javascript-oracle-apex)